# How to check if-else condition in Handlebars

Tags: html, internationalization, handlebars.js

UPDATE: Hello everyone,

I just want to check if yearNumber is equal to 11 or 12 and then put something according to it in this code, but the comparation is not working. It says: "Expected close }} " in the if conditions. I am sure is something really silly. Here's the code:

```
<div>
        {{#if {{yearNumber}} == 11  }}
        <label class="text-label">{{i18n "EDUCATION_EET_GUARANTEE_YEAR_11"}} </label>
        <a id="ed_eetEditGuaranteeAnchor{{yearNumber}}" href="#" class="education-icon-links"
           title="{{i18n "EDUCATION_EET_EDIT_YEAR_11_GUARANTEE_LINK_TITLE"}}">
            <span id="ed_eetEdit{{yearNumber}}GuaranteeIcon" class="icon-edit"></span>
        </a>
        {{else}}
            {{#if {{yearNumber}} == 12  }}
                <label class="text-label">{{i18n "EDUCATION_EET_GUARANTEE_YEAR_12"}} </label>
                <a id="ed_eetEditGuaranteeAnchor{{yearNumber}}" href="#" class="education-icon-links"
                   title="{{i18n "EDUCATION_EET_EDIT_YEAR_12_GUARANTEE_LINK_TITLE"}}">
                    <span id="ed_eetEdit{{yearNumber}}GuaranteeIcon" class="icon-edit"></span>
                </a>
            {{/if}}
        {{/if}}
    </div>
```

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this because Handlebars is logic-less, which means in your case that any kind of evaluations (which comparison really is) in template not allowed by design.

The right way of solving your problem is in using prepared data for rendering. E.g. create flags like `isOddYear: true` / `isEvenYear: true` or similar depends of task. I don't really know what your scope is.

Another way is to create custom helper or extend existing one, e.g. `{{i18n}}` and pass `yearNumber` as argument.